# ArcGIS UserCredentials class in C# (Windows Runtime Apps)

Tags: c#, windows-8.1, gis, arcgis, esri

What's the alternative for `UserCredentials` in Windows Runtime apps? I didn't find this class for Windows runtime apps but this is available in Android.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need get a license for you app.
[License your app](https://developers.arcgis.com/net/desktop/guide/license-your-app.htm) 
Just read through the steps and it will get you started.